# Html dropdown list in android

Tags: android, html, webview

I am using PHP web service in my application there is drop down box in my application and it come  from PHP side. i m using web view to open drop down box. when i select drop down in Samsung galaxy tablet it open and display list but when i try to open in phone 2.2 version or 2.1 it crash application and give me Error like:

```
04-19 17:57:52.822: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44c1bc50 is not valid; is your activity running?
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:468)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.webkit.WebView$InvokeListBox.run(WebView.java:5793)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-19 17:57:52.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```